# How to Design a Second Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, methods

i'm trying to make a second form and acces to all of the main form methods, values, etc... so what i do is:

```
public partial class Principal : Form
{
    public Principal()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
...
```

And in one method i have...

```
private void agregarUsuarioToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form Form2 = new Form();
    Form2.Show();
}
```

I suppose that in Form2 i could acces to all of what i have in my main form, but i wonder how to edit this Form2, how to put buttons or stuff, cause i didnt create a form, just another instance of Form().

Comment: looks like you want to add controls to your form **dynamically**, but that's not really recommended unless you understand how necessary it is. Why not open your `Form2` with the designer and design your UI there?

Answer (score 2):

First of all,  you cannot access the values on the main form from the second form unless the second form has a reference to the first main form.  They are completely separate instances.  The second form is only another copy of the template (the type) that the first form was created from.  All state or data in the first form is specific to the instance of the form (unless declared as `static`). All the controls and visual elements defined in the forms template are created in each of the instances from the template when the form is instantiated (when the constructor runs).

If you need the second form to refer to values on the first form, how to do this best depends on how, when and why.... If you only need to do this when the second form is constructed, and never again during the lifetime of the first form, then you can do it during construction ( `Form Form2 = new Form();` ) if you have a reference to the first instance of the form.  If you need access to the values on the first instance later as well (during the lifetime of the second instance), then you need to add a reference to the first instance as a private field or property of the form so that code on instances of the second form will always have a reference to the first instance.  The best way os to make the second instance an instance of a derived (child) of the first form that has this additional property, and pass the reference to the first form in the constructor to of this second derived form type

```
public SecondForm: Principal
{
    public Form PrincipalForm { get; set; }

    public SecondForm(Principal principalForm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PrincipalForm = principalForm;
    }
    //  other stuff
}
```

then, when you create the second instance, create an instance of `SecondForm` instead.  It will look exactly like the first instance, (cause it derives everything defined on `Principal`), but will have this one additional property.

```
private void agregarUsuarioToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SecondForm Form2 = new SecondForm(firstPrincipalForm);
    Form2.Show();
}
```

now, everywhere on the second forms internal and public methods and code you will have a reference to the first form to do with as you wish